# How do I pull out fields from a custom class using streams? (Without using for/while loops)

Tags: java, java-stream

> I would like to know how to pull out field and make it become a list using streams. For example, if I have a list of Pairs, Pair[2] { Pair<3,5>,Pair<5,7>}, I would like to make it become Integer[3] {3,5,7}. (After using Stream.distinct() to remove the dupicate 5) Pair class is provided if that is needed.

```java
public class Pair<T,U> {
    private final T first;
    private final U second;

    public Pair(T first, U second){
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    T first() {
        return this.first;
    }

    U second(){
        return this.second;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "<" + this.first + ", "+ this.second+">";
    }
}
```

Comment: `pairs.stream().flatMap(p -> Stream.of(p.first(), p.second()))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to turn your stream of pairs into a stream of numbers; to do so, any given pair gets mapped into a variable number of items in the stream. `.map` can only map one thing to one other thing. `flatMap`, on the other hand, can map one thing to any number (even 0) things.

`flatMap` turns an element of the stream, into a stream of whatever you want - these streams are then concatenated together to form a new single stream.

Thus, all you need to do is to turn a `Pair<Integer, Integer>` instance into a stream representing the 2 integers. Java will do the rest:

```
pairs.stream().flatMap(pair -> Stream.of(p.first(), p.second())).distinct().forEach(System.out::println);
```

That would end up printing 3, 5, and 7, as desired.

NB: Pair is bad java style. Java is extensively nominal: Its designed around the notion that things are named. Those pairs of numbers represent something more specific than 'a pair of numbers'. You should make a class that models that exact thing. The alternative is that we do away with, say, a `Person` class and instead make a `Tuple<String, Tuple<Integer, Integer, Integer>, String>` instead of a class with a field `String name;`, `LocalDate birthDate;`, and `String studentId;` or whatnot. Clearly a bad idea.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the infomation. I just learnt about stream and was trying to do the problem twin prime number. Hence, I used stream to create number from 1 to the target number, filter (x -> isprime(x)) and because I can't find any other easy way to compare 2 values in a stream, I made them to Pair using mapToObj then filter to see if the pair is 2 numbers apart and was stuck there because I do not know how to pull out the number from pairs.